# Onstart is called after the listener method is executed

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Why is onstart being called after the listener method is executed?
What should i do to call the onstart method before the listener method is executed?
Using jsf 2.1 and primefaces 4.0.

```
<p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{myBean.onEventMove}"
    update="mygrwlmsg" onstart="setLStorageDateToBean();"
    oncomplete="if(args.facesMessagesAvailable){handleEditEventRequest(args.eventList);scheduleWidget.update();}" />
```

Calls a bean method through remoteCommand

```
function setLStorageDateToBean()
{
    if(typeof(Storage)!=='undefined')
    {
        if((localStorage.startDate || localStorage.getItem('startDate') != null) 
            &amp;&amp; (localStorage.endDate || localStorage.getItem('endDate') != null))
        {
            var sDate = parseInt((localStorage.startDate)/1000);
            var eDate = parseInt((localStorage.endDate)/1000);
            var lCalRefresh = parseInt((localStorage.lastCalRefresh)/1000);

            setLocalStorageDate([{name:'startDate',value:sDate},{name:'endDate',value:eDate},{name:'lastCalRefresh',value:lCalRefresh}]);               
        }
    }
}

<p:remoteCommand name="setLocalStorageDate" actionListener="#{myBean.setDateFromLocaStorage}" >
</p:remoteCommand>
```

Bean Method

```
public void setDateFromLocaStorage()
{
    int startDate = Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("startDate"));
    int endDate = Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("endDate"));
    int lCalRefresh = Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("lastCalRefresh"));

    setlStorStartDate(startDate);
    setlStorEndDate(endDate);
    setlStorLastRefresh(lCalRefresh);       
}
```

Comment: What's in the setLStorageDateToBean() method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution.
Modify the ajax as (remove the listener)

```
<p:ajax event="eventMove" 
    update="mygrwlmsg" onstart="callOnAjax();"
    oncomplete="if(args.facesMessagesAvailable)handleEditEventRequest(args.eventList); 
    scheduleWidget.update();}" />
```

create a new remoteCommand component

```
<p:remoteCommand name="myListener" actionListener="#{myBean.onEventMove}">
</p:remoteCommand>
```

created a new javascript function

```
function callOnAjax(){
   setDateFromLocaStorage();
   myListener();
}
```